# Breaking some WordPress pages, adding classes to <html>

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on MS Azure, there is the contact page that is showing white death screen.
When trying to inspect there is this weird class assigned to `<html>`
Code:

```
 <html class="ie ie9 wf-opensans-n7-inactive wf-opensans-n8-inactive wf-opensans-i4-inactive wf-opensans-n3-inactive wf-opensans-n4-inactive wf-opensans-n6-inactive wf-inactive" lang="en-US"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Tried to deactivate/activate all plugins and refreshing, but still the same issue.
WordPress Env:
Version 5.9.2

Comment: Sorry, there's not enough info here.

Comment: It is similar to the white screen of death issue in WordPress, I can see the screen flashes when loading up and then it disappears entirely.